# Simulate top scroll using javascript setInterval & clearInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, setinterval

I want to simulate scroll by moving body/html frame to the top/upwards by arbitrary amount. I know jQuery scroll or animate function, `.scroll()` and `.animate()`. But I have decided not to use it since it caused conflict between `scrollTop` property in `animate` and `.scroll()` jQuery native function when the animation happens and is still ongoing AND the `.scroll` gets called..

My plan is now to just simulate scroll by moving body/html frame to the top as smooth as possible by some arbitrary amount, and then STOP (clear the interval) when there's a native `scroll` happens (`.scroll()` gets invoked).

I am able to stop the `setInterval` animation when `.scroll()` is called, but I am still not able to move the html object to the top by the amount I want it to "scroll" (which means my code only partially works).

Here is what I have so far:

```
var scrollTop = //Some arbitrary value
var fakeScroll = setInterval(function(){
      console.log(scrollTop);
      var animObj = $('html,body');
      animObj.top = animObj.offset().top + scrollTop;   
    },500);
    $(document).scroll(function(){
        clearInterval(fakeScroll);
    });
```

Appreciate any suggestions/answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this issue without using timer. It turns out that native scroll event and jQuery animate are two different scroll events. What I do is pretty much listen for a particular scroll event that comes from native scroll (DOMMousewheel and mousewheel), and then as it happens, I stop the animation. Thanks for the replies though!

Answer (score 0):

just use `window.scrollTo(0,Y)` while you change the Y value.

Comment: That triggers the $(document).scroll event though, so it will only do it once.

Comment: Set a flag to exit from $(document).scroll while you're running this.

Comment: If you're going down the window.scroll route then window.scrollBy(x,y) would be better than getting the current position and doing a calculation on it.

Answer (score 0):

This works, but I don't think it's what you're looking for as it's not scrolling the page - it's moving the contents...

```
var scrollTop = 1;
var fakeScroll = setInterval(function() {
    console.log(scrollTop);
    var animObj = $('html,body');
    animObj.offset({ top: animObj.offset().top - scrollTop })
}, 500);
$(document).scroll(function() {
    clearInterval(fakeScroll);
});
```